# Uniform density representation in space in terms of Dirac delta and step functions in different types of coordinate systems of different shapes

Tags: mass, charge, coordinate-systems, density, dirac-delta-distributions

As we know, the presence of a particle at a point $\textbf{r}_0$ could be represented by the density function,
$$\rho(\textbf{r}_0)=c\delta^3(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0),$$
Whare, $c$ is a constant and,
$$ \int_v \delta^3(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0)\, d^3r=
\begin{cases}
1,& \text{If }r_0 \in v\\\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$ and,
$$\delta^3(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0)=0 \text{ } \forall \textbf{r}\neq \textbf{r}_0.$$

And for a homogeneous spherical shell of radius $a$, the function in spherical polar coordinates could be,
$$\rho(r)=c\delta(r-a).$$
Similarly what representations could be of a line, sphere, cylinder, cone, disk, circle(specifically) and all others(all are uniform in density) in different types of coordinate systems?

Please try to give an example in all the three types of coordinate systems (cartesian, cylindrical and spherical polar).

Any help will be appreciated. If similar type of questions has already been asked, then please provide the link in comments.

Answer (score 0):

A general density localized on the locus $f(\mathbf x) = 0$ can be written $\rho (\mathbf x) = g(\mathbf x)\delta(f(\mathbf x))$. (Note that if you are working in a space of dimension $d$ and your locus has dimension $k$, you need $f$ to take values in $\mathbb R^{d-k}$ and the $\delta$-function is the $d-k$ dimensional one).

1. A straight line is the loci $A\mathbf x + b = 0$ for some $2\times 3$ matrix $A$ and some $b\in\mathbb R^2$. The uniform density on this line is then given by :
   $$\rho(\mathbf x) = c \delta(A\mathbf x+ b)$$
2. A circle of radius $R$ is the locus $ z= 0, x^2 + y^2 = r^2 = R^2$. The uniform density on the circle is given by :
   $$\rho(\mathbf x) = c\delta(z)\delta(x^2+y^2-R^2) = \frac{c}{2R}\delta (z)\delta(r-R)$$
3. A disk is given by $z= 0, x^2+y^2 = r^2 \leq R^2$. The uniform density is given by :
   $$\rho(\mathbf x)=c\delta(z)\theta(R^2-x^2-y^2)$$
   with $\theta$ the Heaviside step function.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more about the first line? And can you give any refference to know more?